# CUDA Pinned memory implementation error cannot set when device is active in this process

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to implement the pinned memory feature of GPU in my code. For doing that I write my code like this:

```
bool addVectorGPU(float* M, float* N, float* P, int size)
{
// Error return value
cudaError_t status;
cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
// Number of bytes in the matrix.
int bytes = size * sizeof(float);
// Pointers to the device arrays
float *Md, *Nd, *Pd;
// Allocate memory on the device to store each matrix

cudaHostAlloc((void**)&M, bytes, cudaHostAllocMapped);
cudaHostAlloc((void**)&N, bytes, cudaHostAllocMapped);
cudaHostAlloc((void**)&P, bytes, cudaHostAllocMapped);
// Copy the host input data to the device

cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Md, M, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Nd, N, 0);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Pd, P, 0);

// Specify the size of the grid and the size of the block
dim3 dimBlock(TILE_SIZE); // Matrix is contained in a block
dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil((float)size / (float)TILE_SIZE)); 
// Launch the kernel on a size-by-size block of threads
addVectorKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(Md, Nd, Pd, size);
// Wait for completion
cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
// Check for errors
status = cudaGetLastError();
if (status != cudaSuccess) {
std::cout << "Kernel failed: " << cudaGetErrorString(status) <<
std::endl;
cudaFreeHost(M);
cudaFreeHost(N);
cudaFreeHost(P);

return false;
}
// Retrieve the result matrix
//cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Pd, P, 0);
// Free device memory
cudaFreeHost(M);
cudaFreeHost(N);
cudaFreeHost(P);
cudaFree(Md);
cudaFree(Nd);
cudaFree(Pd);
// Success
return true;
}
```

Now for evaluating performance on my device I call this function 1000 times and then compute the average time which it takes to run:

```
int main(){
// Timing data
float tcpuadd, tcpusub, tcpuscale, tgpuadd, tgpusub, tgpuscale, sum, delta, L2norm;
clock_t start, end;
bool success;

//Allocate the four vectors of SIZE floats
float* M = new float[SIZE];
float* N = new float[SIZE];
float* Pcpu = new float[SIZE];
float* Pgpu = new float[SIZE];
//Initialize M and N to random integers
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++){
M[i] = (float) rand()/(RAND_MAX);
N[i] = (float) rand()/(RAND_MAX);
}
printf("Operating on a vector of length %d\n", SIZE);
//Add two vectors and compute timing in CPU
start = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
addVectorCPU(M, N, Pcpu, SIZE);
}

end = clock();
tcpuadd = (float)(end - start) * 1000 / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC / ITERS;
printf( "CPU Addition took %f ms\n", tcpuadd);
//Add two vectors and compute timing in GPU
success = addVectorGPU(M, N ,Pgpu , SIZE);
if(!success)
{
    printf("Device Error!\n");
    return 1;
}
//compute GPU timing
start = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
addVectorGPU(M, N, Pgpu, SIZE);
}
end = clock();
tgpuadd = (float)(end - start) * 1000 / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC / ITERS;
printf("GPU Addition took %f ms\n", tgpuadd);
```

The problem is, for the first time this function works without any errors. But the second time when I call this function, I've got error:

```
cannot set when device is active in this process
```

So does anyone know what it is all about?

Answer (score 5):

If you do a better job of cuda error checking by checking the return value of *each* runtime API call, you'll discover that this error is returned from the second time you call this:

```
cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
```

Note that [description](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g69e73c7dda3fc05306ae7c811a690fac) of this runtime API call:

> If the current device has been set and that device has already been initialized then this call will fail with the error cudaErrorSetOnActiveProcess.

The solution is to call the function only once, at the beginning of your application, not every time you call the `addVectorGPU` function.  Take that call out of the `addVectorGPU` function, and put it in your `main` routine, prior to the first call of `addVectorGPU`.

Based on the question below, there are various other issues with the code:

1. I would suggest implementing proper cuda error checking on *all* kernel calls and all CUDA API calls, rather than once at the end of the routine.
2. The usage of `cudaHostAlloc` is incorrect.  The intent of the program appears to be to pass host pointers to host-resident data to the GPU routine, and then add that data using a zero-copy technique.  This is technically feasible (**although it will be very slow**), but the correct approach would involve the use of [`cudaHostRegister`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c), not `cudaHostAlloc`.  `cudaHostAlloc` creates a *new* allocation, so the existing data passed to the function would not be used or referenced that way.

Here's a worked example, based on what you have shown.  Note that **I personally would not benchmark things this way**, but I am providing this to show that the process can work in an error-free way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

#define TILE_SIZE 512
#define SIZE 1048576
#define ITERS 10

bool addVectorCPU(float *M, float *N, float *P, int size){

  for (int i=0; i< size; i++) P[i] = M[i]+N[i];
  return true;
}
__global__ void addVectorKernel(float *M, float *N, float *P,int  size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < size)
    P[idx] = M[idx]+N[idx];
}

bool addVectorGPU(float* M, float* N, float* P, int size)
{
// Error return value
  cudaError_t status;
// Number of bytes in the matrix.
  int bytes = size * sizeof(float);
// Pointers to the device arrays
  float *Md, *Nd, *Pd;
// Allocate memory on the device to store each matrix

  cudaHostRegister(M, bytes, cudaHostRegisterMapped);
  cudaHostRegister(N, bytes, cudaHostRegisterMapped);
  cudaHostRegister(P, bytes, cudaHostRegisterMapped);
// Copy the host input data to the device

  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Md, M, 0);
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Nd, N, 0);
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Pd, P, 0);

// Specify the size of the grid and the size of the block
  dim3 dimBlock(TILE_SIZE); // Matrix is contained in a block
  dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil((float)size / (float)TILE_SIZE));
// Launch the kernel on a size-by-size block of threads
  addVectorKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(Md, Nd, Pd, size);
// Wait for completion
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  bool res = true;
// Check for errors
  status = cudaGetLastError();
  if (status != cudaSuccess) {
    std::cout << "Kernel failed: " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << std::endl;

    res = false;
    }
// Retrieve the result matrix
//cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&Pd, P, 0);
// Free device memory
  cudaHostUnregister(M);
  cudaHostUnregister(N);
  cudaHostUnregister(P);
// Success
  return res;
}

int main(){
// Timing data
  float tcpuadd, tgpuadd;
  clock_t start, end;
  bool success;

//Allocate the four vectors of SIZE floats
  float* M = new float[SIZE];
  float* N = new float[SIZE];
  float* Pcpu = new float[SIZE];
  float* Pgpu = new float[SIZE];
//Initialize M and N to random integers
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++){
    M[i] = rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX);
    N[i] = rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX);
    }
  printf("Operating on a vector of length %d\n", SIZE);
//Add two vectors and compute timing in CPU
  start = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
    addVectorCPU(M, N, Pcpu, SIZE);
    }

  end = clock();
  tcpuadd = (float)(end - start) * 1000 / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC / ITERS;
  printf( "CPU Addition took %f ms\n", tcpuadd);
//Add two vectors and compute timing in GPU
  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
  success = addVectorGPU(M, N ,Pgpu , SIZE);
  if(!success)
    {
    printf("Device Error!\n");
    return 1;
    }
//compute GPU timing
  start = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
    addVectorGPU(M, N, Pgpu, SIZE);
    }
  end = clock();
  tgpuadd = (float)(end - start) * 1000 / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC / ITERS;
  printf("GPU Addition took %f ms\n", tgpuadd);
}
```

Note I've made a few other changes, as well. For example `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is deprecated, and it's not necessary to use both `cudaThreadSynchronize()` and `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`; they are redundant.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I took that call out of the function and put prior to the first call of addVectorGPU, now for the first time everything works great, but when I call the function inside the loop I got InvalidDevicePointer error

Comment: That's a different question or issue now, right?  Your code is broken in a variety of ways.  You don't seem to understand the correct usage of `cudaHostAlloc`: it is creating a **new** allocation, and overwriting the pointer to the data you passed to the function.  If you want to pose a new question, to discuss this issue, and provide a complete code with proper cuda error checking, I'm sure someone can help you.  Your code posted in this question is incomplete.

Comment: I've added a complete code, based on what you have shown, with the "errors" fixed.  I still would not do things this way, but to each his/her own.