# Until when exactly can I set a CUDA device' (primary context) scheduling policy?

Tags: cuda

I want to set the scheduling policy for (the primary context of a) CUDA device.

Reading the [Runtime API guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html), I notice that:

> If the current device has been set and that device has already been initialized then this call will fail with the error `cudaErrorSetOnActiveProcess`. In this case it is necessary to reset device using `cudaDeviceReset()` before the device's initialization flags may be set.

Setting the current device - I understand. But what exactly does it mean for the device to have been "initialized"? How do I avoid it being "initialized"?

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685521/1593077) question is related.

Answer (score -2):

It seems this means the initialiation of the device's primary context. This, for example

```
cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain(&pc, device_id);
```

should make it so that you can no longer set the policy. This makes sense, since for other contexts you also set such policy once, on context creation.